# How to jump to a UITextField in the next cell of a TableView when editing (of textfield not table) ends

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, first-responder

I'm writing an app with a fixed size table and a couple of UITextFields in each cell. The user needs to input data in the textfields and I want to automatically jump to the next textfield once editing of the current textfield stops.

I have the following code (modded from someplace else on stackoverflow) in the TableViewCell class which works fine to jump to the next field within the cell but doesn't jump to the next cell.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
     // Try to find next responder
    if let nextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
        nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return
}
```

I realise that's because after the second edit the next textfield is not in the same cell but I don't know how to address the textfield in the next cell to make it the FirstResponder. I have an observer on the textfield in the cell to check for changes and updates the array:

```
@IBAction func updatePs(_ sender: Any) {
    psChanged?(ps.text ?? "0")
}
```

where this is in the UITableView cellForRowAt function:

```
cell.psChanged = { value in
    self.psP[indexPath.row] = Int(value) ?? 0
}
```

I though to use this observer to change the FirstResponder from the UITableView cellForRowAt function but I don't know how to.

P.S. I know that working with tags in tables can be problematic but the table is fixed size and rows cannot be deleted.

Comment: If the table is fixed size, then use a static tableview, you don't need cellForRowAt ?  You can just create different textfields in each cell.

Comment: I'm not using a TableViewController but in any case I'm not sure how a Static Table changes that. Do you not still need the cellForRow to populate the cells in static tables? Also not sure it resolves the problem of how to address the next cell when you finish editing in the current cell which is inside the TableViewCell class.